# How to reuse LCOV report from JSCover in Sonar for javascript code coverage

Tags: javascript, sonarqube, jscoverage

I am using JSCover to capture coverage of my javascript files. JSCover outputs coverage in json format and I can use the given html files to view the coverage results.

I am converting the json file to lcov using:

```
java -cp JSCover-all.jar jscover.report.Main --format=LCOV REPORT-DIR SRC-DIRECTORY
```

This is what I set in my sonar.propoerties file

```
sonar.javascript.jstestdriver.reportsPath= C:/...reports
sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPath=C:/.../JSCover/target/jscover.lcov
sonar.dynamicAnalysis=reuseReports
```

But I am not able to see coverage. Why?

Comment: No Errors or results. I am not able to see anything.

Comment: could you attach to this thread the Sonar analysis log file ?